# No redirect in symfony 2.3

Tags: symfony

I use this bundle 
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle

and I want redirect to new page if a condition is not satisfied

my code
Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("foo", name="name",options={"expose"=true})
 */
public function indexAction() {    
  if (1==2) {
     return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('homepage'), 301);
  }    
  ...code...
}
```

but this code does not redirect
(this is an AJAX request)

Comment: What about `if (1!=2) {` ?

Comment: does not enter the exception

Comment: The code seems correct. Have you checked if the `return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('homepage'), 301);` instruction is ever reached ?

Comment: I see with chrome developer tool that `homepage` is load but The page doesen't change

Comment: Are you making an AJAX request?

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez yes with `options={"expose"=true}` in my annotation

Comment: If the page is load, maybe you're receiving no content, or the problem is in the client-side script which receives the data. Can you try using the Console and Network tabs in Chrome Developer Tools, in order to see what are you reciving from the call?

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez I get the contents of the homepage

Answer (score 0):

If it's an ajax request, your redirection send your homepage in response to your request, that doesn't redirect the page who was called the request.

To redirect your page your ajax controller must return the homepage url, after you can redirect your page in javascript with this line

```
document.location.href = [result_of_your_ajax_request]
```

Comment: i can't do it in controller?